# Upgrading STS with all plugins and settings

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I was always disappointed when I have to update Springsource Toolsuite (would also apply to Eclipse, but I never had so much update issues with it), because it takes a rather long amount of time and update function inside of STS doesn't work that well. For example it was not possible for me to upgrade from 2.9.1 to 2.9.2, so I was forced to a reinstallation. In this question I want to show how I do this and I am hoping to get some feedback to improve this process:

1. I always ensure that I have this plugin installed from the market: [P2 Installation Replication](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/p2-installation-replication). It allows me to select and dump all my plugin info into a single XML file. So I start the old version of STS and dump my plugin list to a file with date in the file name to have different versions.
2. Then I close STS and rename the root directory to something like "springsource_old"
3. I download the new version as ZIP file and extract it in a single directory.
4. I use [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/download.html), so I download it and doubleclick on the JAR to install it for the chosen STS install location. Normally Lombok finds the installation if you stick to C:\springsource\.. or similar default locations.
5. Next I update the STS.INI file to force STS to use a specific version of the Java SDK with the -vm flag. If you have a lot of eclipse workspaces to manage it is also helpful to have them shown in the title bar of the window. So I include -showlocation in the INI file. It doesn’t have to appear first, just before -vmargs so that it doesn’t appear to be a JVM argument.
6. Then I start STS, choose the first workspace and close it again. This generates some preference files. What I want to have is the list of all workspaces. STS (Eclipse) is storing the workspace information in a preferences file called "org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs".
   This file is located under "%ECLIPSE_HOME%\configuration.settings" and contains a key named "RECENT_WORKSPACES". So open the file in the backup location, copy the entries, open the new generated file, and copy the settings into it. The next time I start STS, I can choose between all previous used workspaces again.
7. Even when no plugin is installed, STS (Eclipse) can natively open the files with the dumped plugins from step 1 (Import - Install - Install Software Items from File). It also allows to fetch the latest version instead of the version which was saved in the XML file. So I select and fetch all my missing plugins.

What is still missing from your experience? How could I improve this process? It still takes some time.

**Update**
Can't be that I am the only one who has problems with updating STS. Today the update from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0 came and now my STS looks like:
[image: STS after update]
So I still have the issue that after every major update STS is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly was the problem that you had?  In general, you should be able to upgrade from a point release to the next point release with no problems (eg- from 2.9.1 to 2.9.2).

There was a problem at one point, which prevented you from upgrading, but that is fixed now.  See here:  http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?126775-Cannot-update-Grails-Support-from-2-9-1-to-2-9-2&p=413794#post413794

If you are having troubles upgrading, please post to the STS forum and paste the error that p2 is giving you with your message.

Sometimes, when upgrading you can look at the error message and see what component is not being found.  You may need to add a new update site or de-select an incompatible feature.

Comment: At first I had to remove some update sites, because STS couldn't find them. During the update I got an error message which I didn't save. However, since I still have the old version in a backup dir I retried it today and it worked. So I think it was the mentioned problem from the forum.